# How to make FIR filter with Parks-McClellan method in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to make a FIR filter in python with Parks-McClellan method.But I couldn't find how to make.These are the specifications of filter ,i need to change the code Matlab to python,

```
fs = 10000; % sampling frequency fCut1=2000; % cuting frequency fCut2=3000;
fCut3=4000;
df=50;
w=[0 fCut1-df fCut1+df fCut2-df fCut2+df fCut3-df fCut3+df fs/2]/(fs/2); % normalized frequencies
A=[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ];% amplitudes
n=50;
a = 1; % FIR Filter
% Find the characteristics for LP with Parks-McClellan algorithm b = firpm(n,w,A);
titleString = ['Custom Filter, Parks-McClellan optimal FIR, order ' num2str(n)];
   plotFreqPhaseResp(b,a,fs,titleString,[fCut1 fCut2 fCut3])
```

So far i came up with this:

```
import numpy.linalg as lin
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = 10000
fCut1=2000
fCut2=3000
fCut3=4000
df=50
w=np.true_divide([0,fCut1-df,fCut1+df,fCut2-df,fCut2+df,fCut3-df,fCut3+df,fs/2],(fs/2))
A=[0 ,0 ,0 ,1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
N=50

b=sp.firwin(N,w,pass_zero=True)
a=np.array(1.)
w,H=sp.freqz(b,a,worN=512,plot=None)
f=w/(np.pi)

plt.figure()
plt.close('all')
plt.plot(f,abs(H))
plt.grid(True)
```

But it gives an error which is  File "/Users/burakmacbook/Documents/Documents - Burak’s MacBook Air/Uni/3/3:2/DSP/LAB-RO/untitled11.py", line 21, in 
    b=sp.firwin(N,w,pass_zero=True)

File "/Users/burakmacbook/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/fir_filter_design.py", line 400, in firwin
    raise ValueError("Invalid cutoff frequency: frequencies must be "

ValueError: Invalid cutoff frequency: frequencies must be greater than 0 and less than fs/2.
I have to see this [image: plot].

Comment: I think Scipy's `Remez` is much the same... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.remez.html

Comment: Excellent, well done. You can add it as the answer so other folks can see how to do it and then you can accept it as correct and grab the points. Good luck with your project!